Show dialog gauge while preserving function exit code
This function sends api requests.
api_req() {
    # req 1 else return 1
    echo 33
    # req 2 else return 1
    echo 66
    # req 3 else return 1
    echo 100
}

This will return 1 when any of the request fails.
Now, I want to pass it to dialog gauge.
Like this,
if ! api_req | dialog --gauge "Sending requests" -1 -1 0; then
    echo "api requests failed!!"
fi

But it can't detect the fail.
I also tried api_req > >(dialog ...), but this way the dialog is not shown.
How can I get it working?

how do you actually handle "failure"? Your # req 1 doesn't tell us that. How does your script know that a request failed?

and, what kind of API are talking here? Bash only supports invoking executables, so I assume this is some CLI thing; or are you doing the strange "web developer" thing and call API something that is actually specifically an HTTP RPC interface, ideally following REST conventions?

Are you looking for set -o pipefail ? (Inserted prior to the if statement.)  The api_req function would still have to detect the failure and return a result code indicating such, which your code doesn't appear to attempt to do.

@MarcusMüller The # req thing is a comment placed to represent a API request and if the request failed, it return 1. I have edit the question to make it clear.

tmpfile=$(mktemp)
if api_req > "$tmpfile"
then
        dialog --gauge "Sending requests" -1 -1 0 < "$tmpfile"
else
        echo "api requests failed!!"
fi


would that make sense? the idea of dialog --gauge is that it updates while multiple different programs run. if api_req > file implies that api_req is completely finished before dialog gets invoked.
